# day of the week from date in python without calendar modules

Tags: python, python-2.7

Write a function [day] = `weekday(M, D, Y)`, which tells you the day of the week on date M/D/Y. Tell your user what the accepted date ranges are. Do not use any calendar-specific modules or functions.

I found these two piece of code but I don't understand the logic behind them. More specifically, I don't understand where the offset numbers came from.

```
def weekday(M,D,Y):
    offset = [0, 31, 59, 90, 120, 151, 181, 212, 243, 273, 304, 334]
    week   = ['Sunday', 
              'Monday', 
              'Tuesday', 
              'Wednesday', 
              'Thursday',
              'Friday', 
              'Saturday']
    afterFeb = 1
    if M > 2: afterFeb = 0
    aux = Y - 1700 - afterFeb
    # dayOfWeek for 1700/1/1 = 5, Friday
    dayOfWeek  = 5
    # partial sum of days betweem current date and 1700/1/1
    dayOfWeek += (aux + afterFeb) * 365
    # leap year correction
    dayOfWeek += aux / 4 - aux / 100 + (aux + 100) / 400
    # sum monthly and day offsets
    dayOfWeek += offset[M - 1] + (D - 1)
    dayOfWeek %= 7
    return dayOfWeek, week[dayOfWeek]

def weekday(m, d, y):
    # following numbers in the array are suggested by Sakamoto, Lachman, 
    Keith and Craver
    # one for each month
    # and the remaining logic as well
    t = [0, 3, 2, 5, 0, 3, 5, 1, 4, 6, 2, 4]
    y = y - (m<3)
    day = (y + y/4 - y/100 + y/400 + t[m-1] + d)%7;
    # from 0 to 6, weekdays
    if day == 0:
    print "Sunday"
    elif day == 1:
    print "Monday"
    elif day == 2:
    print "Tuesday"
    elif day == 3:
    print "Wednesday"
    elif day == 4:
    print "Thursday"
    elif day == 5:
    print "Friday"
    elif day == 6:
    print "Saturday"
```

Comment: Look at the difference between each two sequential offsets. Hope that helps.

Comment: Offset has 12 values because this is a map of month:day relationships which helps to inject the notion of "how many have passed this year given a month" into the calculation. If you're looking at the second item offset[1]: This is representative of February, where 31 days in the year have already passed.

Answer (score 2):

The program fixes the start date as 1st Jan 1700 which is a friday.  It calculates the difference in the year, month and day.  The offsets are cumulative numbers for the months.  For Jan, one need not add any number to it.  Only 0 is added.  For Feb, one has to add 31 days of Jan, for Mar, one has added 31 days of jan and 28 days of feb (total 59). etc.